# Can I set breakpoints and debug FireDAC source code?

Tags: delphi, firedac, rad-studio

When I create SQL FireDAC Query and call `Open;` procedure, it takes very long to execute SQL Query. I wanted to set breakpoints in RAD Studio in `FireDAC.Comp.Client` Unit to see what is wrong, but breakpoints are not valid and program doesn't stop at that point. Is it possible to build an application so that I could use breakpoints in `FireDAC.Comp.Client` unit.

[image: Screnshot]

Project Options

[image: Project Options]

Best Regards!

Comment: Correctly configured, it is certainly possible to debug into the Firedac source.  Make sure you have "Use Debug DCUs" checked in the debugger options.  You might get further faster using the Sql Server Management Studio Profiler, though.

Comment: Hey Martyn, there is my Project Options. I have "Use Debug DCUs" checked

Comment: According to the [feature matrix](https://www.embarcadero.com/docs/rad-studio-feature-matrix.pdf) (page 21), only architect and enterprise versions have "complete (whatever that means) firedac source code".

Comment: [FDMonitor](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/FDMonitor) can tell you what is going on with FireDac itself. Otherwise to debug a query use some other tool to execute and profile it.

Comment: It is a big project and now I created example project. the breakpoints work now in the example project. Thank you for your comments.